# What is the significance of から?

Tags: particle-から

I'm currently learning the usage of から and got some sample sentences with a similar meaning, but I can't wrap my head around why in one example から　is omitted. If used, is it just giving more emphasis of it being the being, but not really necessary? Does it have something to do with the time?

Example Sentences:

来週は恋人と付き合ってから三年記念日です。

今日は、私と彼が付き合って一年記念日です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of から is optional, and removing it won't change the meaning of the sentence. There is virtually no difference in nuance, and I feel neither is more emphatic than the other.